# sql or postgresql to query table column with comma separator

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL `table1`

```
id | columnA             | columnB
---+---------------------+--------
1  | A 01,A 02,A 03,A 04 | FALSE
2  | A 01,A 02           | FALSE
3  | A 01,A 02,A 03,A 04 | TRUE 
4  | A 01,A 02           | TRUE
```

I used to use below query to find out how many records:

- Query 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB1.table1
WHERE columnA LIKE 'A 04,%'
  OR columnA LIKE '%,A 04,%'
  OR columnA LIKE '%,A 04'
  AND columnB = 'false'
```

- Query 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB1.table1
WHERE columnA LIKE 'A 02,%'
  OR columnA LIKE '%,A 02,%'
  OR columnA LIKE '%,A 02'
  AND columnB = 'false'
```

Is there better way to just have one query to find which column has 'A 02' or 'A 04' and 'FALSE'?

Comment: Tough luck, comma separated data... Will cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: What does "clinic" mean?

Comment: Typo error. I corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial posted query indicates you're searching for text at the beginning of the string (A 04,), at the end of the string (,A 04) or in the middle of the string (,A 04,). These can simply be reduced to anywhere in the string or simply (A 04). Combining with the (A 02) predicate value and the columnB predicate we get

```
select *
  from db1.table1
 where not columnB
   and (columnA like '%A 02%' or columnA like '%A 02%');
```

But I reiterate having multiple values in the same column, or even same data in separate columns with in a row is very bad design. Ther should be in sepreate rows.

Comment: This will fail real quick with higher values, e.g. `BA 02` and `A 021`. The array or regex versions are more robust.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=230a7e83b8fc890f6af2615dff863ee0)

```
SELECT *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    columnB = false AND ARRAY['A 02', 'A 04', 'clinic 02'] && string_to_array(columnA, ',')
```

1. Create an array out of your interesting values: `ARRAY['value1','value2']`
2. Convert your string list into an array: `string_to_array(list, ',')`
3. Use the `&&` comparator to check if both arrays overlap, meaning if both arrays share at least one element.

[Further reading: Postgres arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

---

**Note**: You should think about normalizing your data instead of holding some string separated values in one column. Your current way could lead in many problems.

Comment: Alternative would be `WHERE columnB = false AND columnA ~ ,?A 0[24],?`, not sure how regex performance compares to creating an array for every record.

Comment: @404 Very nice idea! In the fiddle engine the query planner show not very different cost results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2261efe788b96e3ff79ef8a83cfb3ffa But it's definitely worth a try with the real data.

Comment: What could be the problem? When query? Best approach to store multiple value?

Comment: Hard to query has you can see here: You always need to split the value. Better approach is taking a simple array instead of a concatenated string. Best approach is to store every value in its own row. In that case you could simply use WHERE to filter. Furthermore indexes can be appended. And if you need the concatenated string you simply do a GROUP BY and string_agg()

Comment: Store every value in its own row. The application behave as one row per unique id only. One unique id has many values. Unless business logic changed, otherwise I couldn't see how designer can change the model. Make many columns not right too. As the values can be up to 50 different values .

Comment: then add an additional id column for each row.

Comment: And there is no problem: If your app needs to get such a data set, as I said, you could return the query result from a GROUP BY. Your database and table design should never depend on your application's design. Store the data as normalized as possible to work with as good as possible and aggregate the data afterwards to whatever the app needs

Comment: Got it. New id for each unique id, group same unique id to find the relevant values. Anyway, I'm not designer. Could be they have specific scenario especially for API layer.

Comment: I haven't try the query. Away fr pc now.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data model!  Storing multiple values in a single column is very bad -- and Postgres has many better alternatives than strings.  That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really bad decisions.

You can use `like` for this purpose:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB1.table1
WHERE ',' || columnA || ',' ~ ',A 02,|,A 04,' AND
      NOT columnB   -- assuming this is boolean
```

For a single value, you would use:

```
WHERE ',' || columnA || ',' LIKE '%,A 02,%' AND
      NOT columnB   -- assuming this is boolean
```

Comment: What could be the potential problems? What is the best approaches if not store it in one column? Create many column does not sounds right.

Comment: @user2201789 . . . The values should be stored in separate rows of a junction/association table.